# Training custom Swedish spacy model

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

my intention was to train a custom POS-Tagger and Dependency Parser in spaCy for the swedish language. 
I followed the instructions on https://spacy.io/usage/training and trained the models on the Swedish-Talbanken treebank conllu files. 
These steps went well and I ended up with a custom model. Then I loaded the model and tried a little example:

```
nlp = spacy.load(name=os.path.join(spacy_path, 'models/model-best'))
doc = nlp(u'Jag heter Alex Nilsson. Hon heter Lina')
# My name is Alex Nilsson. Her name is Lina

for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_)

# OUTPUT:

#Jag PRON nsubj
#heter VERB ROOT
#Alex PROPN obj
#Nilsson PROPN flat:name
#. PUNCT punct
#Hon PRON nsubj
#heter VERB parataxis
#Lina PROPN obj
```

Both POS-Tagger and Dependency Parser seem to work. What didn’t work was the sentence segmentation and the noun chunks.

```
for sent in doc.sents:
    print(sent.text)

# OUTPUT:

#Jag heter Alex. Hon heter Lina

for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    print(chunk.text, chunk.root.text, chunk.root.dep_,
          chunk.root.head.text)

# OUTPUT:

#
```

So, no splitting for the sentences and no output for noun chunks. As far as I understand spaCy uses the Dependency Parser for both functionalities. But as shown above the Dependency Parser should work just fine. Is there something more that it required for these two to work? Maybe I am missing something obvious?

I am thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure about this, but I think the sentencing is working, since doc.sents is not empty. It just seems to be working badly. I would try to parse a larger text (but still small) and maybe using longer sentences. Since the sentencizer builds sentences by finding the dependent tokens, longer sentences are unlikely to merge into a single one.

As for the noun_chunks, my understanding (from [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/adding-languages#_title)) is that the language must have a noun_chuncks method defined in the syntax_iterators.py file of the language data. It doesn't seem to be automatically trained.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I might found the error. It seems that spacy expects different documents for training, not just single sentences. I didn't took this into account. I retrain the model and check again.

Comment: It indeed was the -n parameter of train. No the sentence segmentation works as expected.